# How to limit the amount of pages displayed in the links of will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I want to make my current will_paginate that looks like this:

```
<-Previous 1 2 3 4 5 Next->
```

Look like this

```
<-Previous 1 2 Next->
```

How do I control the amount of pages that can be displayed between previous and next?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `inner_window` and `outer_window` properties can be used to manipulate how many page links you see on each page. You can pass them to the `will_paginate` method on your view (if you only want to limit the number of links for one page).

If you want to limit the number of pages shown throughout your application, the best approach is an initializer file (call it something like will_paginate.rb). You can set global configuration options like so:

```
WillPaginate::ViewHelpers.pagination_options[:inner_window] = 3
WillPaginate::ViewHelpers.pagination_options[:outer_window] = 2
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed response! If I wanted to pass it to the will_paginate method how would that look? <%= will_paginate, :inner_window => 3 %> I think I get some nomethod inner_window errors if I do it like this.

Comment: You should be able to call <%=will_paginate @models, :inner_window => 5%>